# Verilog concurrent assignment to register

Tags: fpga, verilog

Given two separate `always @( posedge clk )` block in the same module, what happens if I assign two different values in each of them respectively to the *same* register?

I guess the question is in general, how do you ensure you don't have weird side effects in your design?

Comment: In simulation or in synthesis?

Comment: @ThePhoton I guess in synthesis because that is supposed to be the real thing?

Comment: I would recommend you to give it a try. Any decent toolchain will give you a clean answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess the question is in general, how do you ensure you don't have weird side effects in your design?

Don't alter the same register in different always blocks, it will either give you some odd behavior or not be synthesized.

You can do it if the always blocks are driven by signals that will never happen at the same time, otherwise you are designing a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

Answer (score 1):

Synthesis tools *never* allow you to make assignments to the same register from more than one `always` block. It's up to you to select the logic from one `always` block from either registers or combinational logic from other blocks